# Blogengine.net asp.net exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, blogengine.net

I was using [blogengine.net](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/) and was configured to run on XML provider. But today when I opened the site, it's giving an exception.

```
You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.
[MySqlException (0x80004005): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.]
```

That's weird because I'm using XML as provider and this exception is saying that I'm using SQL. I have also viewed web.config with these lines

```
 <BlogEngine>
    <blogProvider defaultProvider="DbBlogProvider" fileStoreProvider="XmlBlogProvider">
      <providers>
        <add description="Xml Blog Provider" name="XmlBlogProvider" type="BlogEngine.Core.Providers.XmlBlogProvider, BlogEngine.Core" />
        <add connectionStringName="BlogEngine" description="Sql Database Provider" name="DbBlogProvider" type="BlogEngine.Core.Providers.DbBlogProvider, BlogEngine.Core" />
      </providers>
    </blogProvider>
    <blogFileSystemProvider defaultProvider="XmlBlogProvider">
      <providers>
        <add description="Xml Blog Provider" name="XmlBlogProvider" type="BlogEngine.Core.Providers.XmlFileSystemProvider, BlogEngine.Core" />
        <add storageVariable="BlogEngine" description="Sql Database Provider" name="DbBlogProvider" type="BlogEngine.Core.Providers.DbFileSystemProvider, BlogEngine.Core" />
        <!--<add storageVariable="\\UNCPath\BlogFiles" description="UNC Path Provider" name="UNCBlogProvider" type="BlogEngine.Core.Providers.UNCFileSystemProvider, BlogEngine.Core"/>-->
      </providers>
    </blogFileSystemProvider>
  </BlogEngine>
```

### Updated

```
[MySqlException (0x80004005): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.]
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() +342
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId) +383
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force) +121
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult() +1109
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +2538
   BlogEngine.Core.Providers.DbBlogProvider.FillBlogs() +274
   BlogEngine.Core.Blog.get_Blogs() +182
   BlogEngine.Core.Blog.get_CurrentInstance() +516
   BlogEngine.Core.Right.EnsureBlogInstanceDataLoaded() +38
   BlogEngine.Core.Right..cctor() +777

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'BlogEngine.Core.Right' threw an exception.]
   BlogEngine.Core.Right..ctor() +0

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +138
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +105
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +1481
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +191
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture) +27
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.CreateNonPublicInstance(Type type, Object[] args) +82
   System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1 moduleList) +229
   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext) +1114
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +140
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +402
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +343

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +579
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +112
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +712
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: is that a MySql Database that you are using..?

Comment: no im using xml you can see im using defaultProvider="XmlBlogProvider" in web.config . It was working fine until today

Comment: Why do you think the error message is actually correct ? What does the call stack say is being executed ?

Comment: i have added call stack summary please see it